# What's the code to figure out this question when using Rstudio?

Tags: r

There are one hundred different plots, each plot has two different kinds of data, ECM and AM, just as the picture show. I want to figure out the ratios of AM to ECM in those 100 plot respectively, how to solve this conveniently? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but if you want to know number of AM and ECM, simply use

```
summary(as.factor(dataframe$E))
AM ECM  
10  15
```